# GraphQL filter search query returns below error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a following graphQL query.

```
export const GET_CARDS = gql`
    query GetContentCards($filter: { $limit: Int, $keywords: "", $types: [PODCAST]}) {
        contentCards(filter: { limit: $limit, keywords: $keywords, types: $types }) {
            edges {
                ...on Podcast {
                    name
                    image {
                        ...Image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fragment Image on Image {
            uri
        }
    }
`;
```

When I run this I get below error in google dev console.

```
syntaxError.mjs:8 Uncaught GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "{".
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
query GetContentCards($limit: Int, $types: [PODCAST]) {
        contentCards(filter: { limit: $limit, keywords: "", types: $types }) {
            edges {
                ...on Podcast {
                    name
                    image {
                        ...Image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fragment Image on Image {
            uri
        }
    }
```

1. I never define a variable as an object like `$filter: {...}`.
2. remove the `$keywords: ""` from the variables, you can assign it directly